# My neutered dog incision

Tags: neutering

My male dog just got neutered about 3 days ago and I’m really concerned about the way his incision site looks like.  I was wondering if that’s the way it looks as it’s healing or if it’s infected !!?[image]

Comment: you need to take your dog to the vet for this,it does not look good at all so your vet is the one to ask about this(let the vet take a look at the picture if it is hard to get an apointment right now).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your dog cannot be diagnosed over the internet.

A vet needs to evaluate your dog to determine whether infection is present. Certainly it looks like some possible purulent discharge, and antibiotics may be warranted.

You should contact your vet who did the surgery, to have them take a look. In the meantime, make sure to keep your dog's e-collar on.